# Make skype account adult

Tags: skype

Can't sign in to skype anymore since my date of born was not wrong. How to escape from this or get parents permition?

According to [Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_mac-skype_startms-skype_signms/skype-is-asking-for-parental-consent/4c90a2e7-3959-4d16-9150-675e2f1f929d) I should have option `I’m a adult-why am I seeing this?` But I don't see it.

How to retain skype account?

[image]

Comment: So did you try to do what it says and use browser to go to [account.microsoft.com](https://acount.microsoft.com)?